# StorybookJS How do I integrate Bootstrap 5 into a Storybook implementation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, storybook

I'm currently working on building a storybook and looking to implement Bootstrap 5 into it. Is the best way of implementing it is by using a preview-head.html file within the .storybook directory? I've looked through the documentation and YouTube videos but can't see anything about framework implementation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using Storybook with Bootstrap 5 - NPM package

The official documentation for Storybook offers a guide on how to add Bootstrap 5 to a Storybook project under the section "Configure Storybook" and sub-section "Overview - Configure story rendering".

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/overview#configure-story-rendering

> At the time of writing it reads:

Configure story rendering
To control the way stories are rendered and add global decorators and parameters, create a .storybook/preview.js file. This is loaded in the Canvas tab, the “preview” iframe that renders your components in isolation. Use preview.js for global code (such as CSS imports or JavaScript mocks) that applies to all stories.

#### Steps

Here are the steps to add Bootstrap 5 to a Storybook project:

1. Install [Bootstrap 5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) by running the following command:
   `npm install bootstrap`
2. Import the Bootstrap CSS file in the .storybook/preview.js file.

It should look like this:

```
// .storybook/preview.js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

3. Restart Storybook and you should see the Bootstrap styles applied to the stories.

Comment: This doesn't work in .storybook/preview.ts, which is the default for how storybook installs :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to import Bootstrap into your Storybook project, which is what I think you are asking about when you are saying "integrate".

For example:

```
// src/stylings/index.scss

import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

```
// .storybook/preview.tsx

import '../src/styles/index.scss'
```

Or you could import it from its CDN:

```html
<!-- .storybook/preview-head.html -->

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Read more here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/ or simply here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/introduction/